# Is there an equivalent of Python's fractions.Fraction (bignum/arbitrary-precision fraction/rational number class)?

Tags: c++, math, fractions, bignum, arbitrary-precision

I'd like to do some arbitrary-precision math on rational numbers, e.g.:

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> Fraction(318483434, 1980410394309430943904903) * Fraction(34913483843843843843, 902490524905498548954894898889923232)
Fraction(5559683113745453573439198431, 893650808144311844544465740142994088494601632782777989203248)
```

Is there a library which would allow me to do this in a straightforward way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using boost, you can use `boost::rational` in conjunction with `boost::multiprecision::cpp_int` (arbitrary-precision integer):

```
#include <boost/rational.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

using boost::multiprecision::cpp_int;

typedef boost::rational<cpp_int> fraction_t;
```

For some reason, the constructor `fraction_t("1", "2")` doesn't work, although `cpp_int("1")` does, so if you need large int literals, you can use this helper function to not require explicit construction of `cpp_int` objects each time you create a fraction:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
fraction_t fraction(A a, B b) 
{
    return fraction_t(cpp_int(a), cpp_int(b));
}
```

[Usage](https://ideone.com/aJf1d5):

```
cout << fraction(318483434, "1980410394309430943904903") * 
        fraction("34913483843843843843", "902490524905498548954894898889923232") << endl;
```

Output:

```
5559683113745453573439198431/893650808144311844544465740142994088494601632782777989203248
```